# Readiness probe failing when second pod gets scheduled to the same container in k8s

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-service

I have a k8s service which maps to pod deployment with 2 replicas and is exposed as clusterIp service. I am seeing an issue when the 2nd pod gets scheduled to the same node the readiness probe (http call to an api in container port) is failing with "unable to connect error" . Is this due to some port conflict?

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: demo-deployment
  namespace: demo
  labels:
    app: demo
spec:
  replicas: 2
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 0
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: demo
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        checksum/config: {{ include (print $.Template.BasePath "/app-configmap.yaml") . | sha256sum }}
      labels:
        app: demo
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: demo
        image: demo-app-image:1.0.1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8081
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthcheck
            port: 8081
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          periodSeconds: 60
          failureThreshold: 3
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 15
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthcheck
            port: 8081
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          periodSeconds: 10
          failureThreshold: 3
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 15
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config-volume
          mountPath: /config/app

      volumes:
      - name: config-volume
        configMap:
          name: demo-configmap
          items:
          - key: config
            path: config.json
      nodeSelector:
        usage: demo-server
```

Comment: Please show some logs, or at least the configuration, otherwise this is impossible to diagnose.

Comment: Added configuration

Comment: We are still unable to reproduce your issue as we have no access to your `demo-app-image:1.0.1`. What exactly do you have in logs ? Are both replicas up and running ?